# Is there a way to be able to add two instances of a class?

Tags: python, function, class, operators

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, n, d):
        self.n = n
        self.d = d
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}/{}".format(self.n, self.d)
```

like so. I want to implement different operators, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Override `__add__`, `__sub__`, etc. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Comment: What are `f1` and `f2` supposed to represent?

Comment: f1 and f2 are two instances of the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should help:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __add__(self, other):
        """Addition operation"""
        return A(self.a + other.a)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        """Subtraction operation"""
        return A(self.a - other.a)

x = A(10) + A(8) # x.a == 18
x = A(10) - A(8) # x.a == 2
```